# How do I retrieve a data set from GitHub using the !curl Unix command in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: database, curl, github, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to retrieve data from an Excel file format in a GitHub repository using the !curl command in Jupyter-Notebook, or alternatively from a file stored locally on my PC.

I created a new Jupyter Notebook and ran a command to access an http domain on GitHub but Notebook returned the following error - 'Not Found' and the display of an empty table of results. The aim is to try and follow instructions given in a course tutorial to see if I can create a functional notebook with access to data.

!curl https://github.com/lynstanford/JupyterBUTI/BUTI_Copy.xlsx

What have I done wrong? Do I need to save the file in .csv format?

Error Message returns: 'Not Found'
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0
100     9    0     9    0     0      2      0 --:--:--  0:00:03 --:--:--     2
100     9    0     9    0     0      2      0 --:--:--  0:00:03 --:--:--     2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this information on 'notebooks.azure.com'. I simply need to set up my Working Directory for Jupyter Notebooks correctly so the !curl command will access and read the file from the correct location. [A Jupyter Notebook example of the command.](https://github.com/lynstanford/JupyterBUTI/blob/master/screenshot.png)